# Cleaner solution to returning generic objects (e.g. Lists) in Java

Tags: java, generics, jpa, casting

I'm working with the JPA API (Hibernate-backed), and have the following code:

```
public List<?> getGenericListing(Class<?> clazz) {
    //Other logic comes before...
    Query qry = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, clazz);
    return qry.getResultList(); //Returns an untyped list, part of JPA spec
}

public List<SpecificObject> getSpecificListing() {
    return (List<SpecificObject>) getGenericListing(SpecificObject.class);
}
```

Is there a better way to return the `List<?>` other than type-casting it against the List of SpecificObject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the cast into `getGenericListing`:

```
public <T> List<T> getGenericListing(Class<T> clazz) {
    //Other logic comes before...
    Query qry = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, clazz);
    return (List<T>) qry.getResultList(); //Returns an untyped list, part of JPA spec
}
```

Answer (score 3):

what's the nature of your sql? If dynamic queries feature isn't necessary to you then you can use this solution:

```
public <T> List<T> getGenericListing(Class<T> clazz) {
    //Other logic comes before...
    TypedQuery<T> qry = entityManager.createNamedQuery(sql, clazz);
    return qry.getResultList();
}
```

where 'sql' is a name of NamedNativeQuery, for example declared as

```
@NamedNativeQuery( 
    name="sql_name", 
    query="SELECT * " + 
          "FROM foo_table t " + 
          "WHERE t.foo_field = ? ", 
    resultClass=fooEntityClass.class 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you don't need to cast the result, and namedQueryName is just the name of named query.

```
public <T> List<T> getGenericListing(final String namedQueryName,Class<T> clazz) {
      TypedQuery<T> qry = em.createNamedQuery(namedQueryName, clazz);
      return qry.getResultList(); 
}
```

Additionally I prefer using xml to store named queries rather than strings in java class - it's more maintainable, so my persistence.xml has:

```
        <mapping-file>META-INF/Finders.xml</mapping-file>
```

Following this approach you can change query without compiling project which I find helpful, excerpt from Finder.xml

```
<named-query name="Country.findCountryByShortNameAndLocale">
    <query>
        SELECT c FROM Country c WHERE c.Country.shortName = :shortName AND c.language.locale = :locale
    </query>
</named-query>
```